Proving $ \top \vdash \exists x (A(x) \to \forall y A(y)) $ in First-Order Logic
I’m trying to prove the statement:
$$
\top \vdash \exists x (A(x) \to \forall y A(y))
$$
in first-order logic. This statement seems a bit unintuitive at first glance, as it involves both existential and universal quantifiers within an implication. I would appreciate some help understanding why this statement is valid and how to construct a formal proof.

What I’ve Thought So Far:

The statement involves:

$ \top $ (true, i.e., no assumptions).
An existential quantifier $\exists x$ around an implication.
Inside the implication: $A(x)$ implies $\forall y A(y)$.


My intuition is that the choice of $x$ does not necessarily require $A(x)$ to be true. The implication $A(x) \to \forall y A(y)$ is vacuously true if $A(x)$ is false.

Therefore, to satisfy the existential quantifier $\exists x$, I can select an arbitrary $x$ where $A(x)$ does not hold. This would make the implication $A(x) \to \forall y A(y)$ true.



Where I’m Stuck:

I’m not entirely confident about this reasoning.
I’d like to know how to formally prove this step-by-step using natural deduction or a formal proof system.

Could someone explain why this statement holds and walk me through the proof?

Duplicate. Search for "drinker's paradox".

Hint: try Existential Introduction. Write back if you're still stuck.

Hint: Consider two cases: (1) $\forall x: A(x)$, or (2) $\neg \forall x: A(x)$.
